# How to convert iOS backup from 4.0 to 3.x

Tags: ios, backup, iphone, restore

Is there a way to convert an iOS 4 backup to format that was used in iOS 3.
I have an iPhone 3G and iOS 4 runs really slow on it. I have succesfuly downgraded the firmware back to 3.1.3 but now I can't restore data backup because the backup format is only for iOS 4. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to exchange backups for each major versions.

but you can give that a try, first you need to **downgrade the firmware**, and for the moment you can't downgrade from 4.x to 3.x as it already updated the baseband and there is nothing you can do now unless using hacker tricks that you need to find in specialized forums.

Then after update the device with the firmware, you just chose "**restore backup**" on your first connection to iTunes and pass the activation (if an iPhone)

**Remember one BIG thing**:

iPhone 3G runs iOS 4.0 really slow, but **iOS 4.1 is sooo much faster**! you should upgrade! I did and I was impressed with the speed, though now wife has it as I bought the 4th version of the iPhone.

Comment: Comment about the BIG thing: I wonder why I didn't see any groundbreaking difference after 4.1 upgrade (my 3G was a lot faster with pre 4.0 versions).

Comment: ohh, but it's so dang fast with 4.1, Navigon takes less than one minute to load and get a signal... while with 4.0.2 It would take sometimes, and I'm not kidding, 4 to 5 minutes, it was terrible! (iPhone4 takes around 15 sec, now) :)